# Create custom class to Deserialize object to check Data Integrity

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, data-integrity

What i have done in serialization
1. Created object, encrypted it with some algorithm 
2. Serialized the encrypted object and save in file
3. Encrypted the file

What i have done in deserialization
1. Decrypted File
2. Read the file and Deserialized the object
3. Decrypted the object
4. ?
5. use object

What i need in step 4 
After decrypting object i want to check object contains the same data as it is when it's serialized (no database should be involved)

I have tried storing object data in database and then comparing , it's works but requires too much time

Comment: you could use a hash like sha or md5 for verifying the integrity of the data by generating a hash before serialization and writing it  and then after deserialization calculating the hash again and comparing it with the previous one

Comment: Ohh! Nice i will try it right away

Comment: If you found that the comment answered your question,  i could write write it as an answer and you could close this question by marking it as accepted. So  did it solve the problem?